# Using facebook's FriendPickerFragment to find friends with same app

Tags: android, facebook

On the facebook SDK "What’s New in Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android" page, under "Ready-to-Use native UI views" it states: 
"Friend Picker lets people tag friends in an Open Graph action or **find other people who installed your app**."
This sounds very useful, but on the FriendPickerFragment reference page there is no information regarding what information to include in the Bundle arg to get additional configuration information. I'm working on an Android game and I want to allow users to start a game with other USERS who are also facebook friends, but can't figure out how to get a list of friends with the same app installed. Does anyone know **what argument(s) can be passed into FriendPickerFragment to get a list of other app users?** Thanks so much in advance, please let me know if more information is required to make this question more relevant/make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
friendPickerFragment.setFilter(new GraphObjectFilter<GraphUser>() {
        @Override
        public boolean includeItem(GraphUser graphObject) {
            if(graphObject.asMap().containsKey("installed") && (Boolean) graphObject.asMap().get("installed"))
                return false;
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is only checking if the user has installed my app or not.

Comment: make sure you add "installed" to the fields that will be returned.  "intent.putExtra(FriendPickerFragment.EXTRA_FIELDS_BUNDLE_KEY, "installed""

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the BooleanOG sample app that ships with the SDK. It shows an example of how to filter the results based on friends with your app installed.

Comment: I think I found what you're referring to. Line 211 is: friendPickerFragment.setExtraFields(Arrays.asList(INSTALLED)); I'm going to try this out as soon as I can, and if it works as expected, I'll come back and mark this as the answer. Thank you VERY much, facebook has been less than helpful!

Comment: This appears to be the solution. I'm having more trouble than expected implementing friendPickerFragment ('ready to use UI elements' my @$$. The Scrumptious tutorial makes use of a ton of classes to implement a list of friends and I'm looking for something MUCH simpler).

Comment: Have a look at the FriendPickerSample and the HelloFacebookSample for simpler uses of the friend picker. Scrumptious is a much more involved tutorial/app.

Answer (score 1):

By default FriendPickerFragment display the list of friends that have installed your app. You can change the displayed list specifying the type (setFriendPickerType()).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Scores API does it for you

> The list is sorted by descending score value, so it returns friends with the highest scores first.

RF: [Scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores/)